# Make ul 100% height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have found this Facebook timeline look a like however I can not get the height of the ul

```
<ul class="timeline">...</ul>
```

100% height so that when there is less content the line in the middle fills the pages height.

I am trying to make the following 'line' fill the rest of the height of the page.

```
.timeline:before {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
content: " ";
width: 3px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -1.5px;
}
```

Adding 'height:100%;' to .timeline does not work.

I have created a fiddle to play with: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4EJNt/1/

Comment: Could you be  a little more specific? What line in the middle? If you mean the grey one on the left, it fills the height for me on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EJNt/7/)</kbd>

The problem is that your `.container` element isn't at `height:100%`, so when you try to add the `height:100%` property to your `<ul>` element, is technically **is** filling all of the space available, it's just that your `.container` element is the same height as your `<ul>` element.

And at least in your fiddle, your `body` tag is **also** the same height as your `.container` element. Try adding these styles to your fiddle and you'll see what I mean:

```
html, body, .container, ul.timeline
{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: It was missing #div-timeline too, so I added it in and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS,  there is excessive margin from the bootstrap.css file.

```
div.container > div.page-header {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4EJNt/4/